# Unable to process web service request with soap xml format in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

while passing data to request using soap xml format getting error like this,

```
              @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                        "<soap:Body>\n"
                        "<uploadFileFrTask xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                        "<taskId>%@</taskId>"
                        "<fileType>%@</fileType>"
                        "<date>%@</date>"
                        "<fileName>%@</fileName>"
                        "<fileBytes>%@</fileBytes>"
                        "<byteLenth>%@</byteLenth>"
                        "<taskHistory>%@</taskHistory>"
                        "</uploadFileFrTask>"
                        "</soap:Body>"
                        "</soap:Envelope>"
```

using this format getting error like this ,

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode><faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (class [B -&gt; class java.lang.String)</faultstring><detail><ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">DESKTOP-D4LEADQ</ns1:hostname></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

If any one look into this issuance...Thanks in advance..